# How to solve this simple error in delphi

Tags: delphi, if-statement

Im using a IF code in a IF code :

```
if Label1.Caption=Label2.Caption then
begin
  Form1.Close;
  Form2.Show;
end
if Label2.Caption=Label3.Caption then
begin
  Form1.Close;
  Form2.Show;
end
end;
```

I keep getting a error of ***missing operator of semicolon***
Could someone please how to make a simple IF in an IF with more lines(begin/end) ?

Comment: I have to state that this is one of the most basic syntax rules of the entire Pascal language.

Comment: On the other hand, your code is definitely fragmented. What if both cases `Label1.Caption=Label2.Caption` and `Label2.Caption=Label3.Caption` evaluate to True? Then your code `Form1.Close; Form2.Show;` would execute twice.

Comment: And on yet another note, if you close your main form (`Form1`) then you're killing the entire application. I don't think that's what you want to do, since you're trying to show another form right after that.  I would recommend use `Form1.Hide` instead. That is, unless `Form1` isn't your main form, which in most cases it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to separate statements with a semi-colon.

```
begin
  if ... then 
  begin
    ....
  end; // <--- add missing semi colon
  if ... then 
  begin
    ....
  end; // <-- semi-colon not needed, but looks silly if omitted
end;
```

The two if statements in your code need to be separated. Pascal syntax requires statements to be separated by semi-colons. The official language guide has comprehensive coverage of this area of the language's syntax: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements

One final point. You indicate twice in the question that the second if is nested inside the first. That is not so. They are separate statements, one after the other. So if both conditions evaluate to True you will call `Form1.Close` twice, and `Form2.Show` twice. It seems likely that's not your intention, but I'm not in a position to guess what your true intent is.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it directs the actual problem :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean to want this:

```
if Label1.Caption = Label2.Caption then
  if Label2.Caption = Label3.Caption then
  begin
    Form1.Close;
    Form2.Show;
  end;
```

Which can be shortened into:

```
if (Label1.Caption = Label2.Caption) and (Label2.Caption = Label3.Caption) then
begin
  Form1.Close;
  Form2.Show;
end;
```

Comment: I'm sure you mean **or** instead of **and** ! Your `and` is wrong. 'Form1' should be closed : if `Label1.Caption = Label2.caption OR Label2.caption = Label3.caption` !!

Comment: Indeed, `and` needs to be `or` to match the OP's intention.